# Acceder a un objeto de la respuesta que llega de una API en Angular

Tags: angular

Buen día, tengo una duda en como consultar un objeto que viene de una respuesta al consultar una API.

Este es la respuesta de la API (lo que quiero obtener es el `nombre` del `asesorVenta`)

```
    "correoElectronico": "example@example.com",
    "telefono": "9988776655",
    "asesorVenta": {
      "nombre": "Juanito",
      "apellidoPaterno": "Perez",
      "apellidoMaterno": "Perez"
    },
    "fecha": "2020-05-01T15:46:05",
```

En mi modelo tengo las misma propiedades que en la respuesta:

```
export class EmpresaModel {
    public correoElectronico: string;
    public telefono: string;
    public asesorVenta: Array<
    { 
        nombre: string,
        apellidoPaterno: string,
        apellidoMaterno: string
    }
   >;
   public fecha: string;
constructor(){}
}
```

Entonces al momento de querer imprimirlo en el HTML lo hago de esta manera:

```
<p>{{empresa.asesorVenta.nombre}}</p>
```

Lo cual me ocasiona un error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (FormEmpresaComponent.html:173)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:30833)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29870)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30230)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:30158)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29871)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30230)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:30187)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:29865)
    at callViewAction (core.js:30230)
```

La pregunta es si estoy haciendo algo mal, o si en mi modelo estoy definiendo mal el objeto "asesorVenta" que me llega de la respuesta de la API.

Comment: No es el mismo modelo, `asesorVenta` no es un `Array<T>`, sino on objeto.

Comment: Esa es la duda que tengo, no se muy bien como definir ese objeto en mi modelo de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asesorVenta` está mal definido puesto que no es un arreglo. Esta es una manera de resolverlo:

```
export class EmpresaModel {
    
constructor(
   public correoElectronico?: string,
   public telefono?: string,
   public asesorVenta?: iAsesorVenta,
   public fecha?: string,
){}
}
```

Y asesor venta se crea como una interfaz.

```
export interface iAsesorVenta {
        nombre: string
        apellidoPaterno: string
        apellidoMaterno: string
}
```

Esto es para facilitar un poco el código.

## [Ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etnjhg)

Comment: Algunas cosas a mencionar, ... Los nombres de las interfaces, tipos y clases deben estar escritos en *PascalCase* (y el prefijo "*I*" para interfaces en *Typescript* no es del todo recomendado según las guías de estilos). `EmpresaModel` debería ser también una interfaz; los DTO deben carecer de lógica. Las propiedades de `EmpresaModel` no deben ser opcionales, a menos que la API sea explícita en ese punto.

Comment: He implementado lo de la interfaz para optimizar código, pero sigo sin poder obtener el nombre de asesorVenta,

Comment: @MiguelAngel por favor comprueba en tu servicio con `console.log` que verdaderamente estés recibiendo los datos. Y tambien para fin de debugueo, por favor imprime en el html `{{empresa | json}}`. Pones lo que te resulte en tu pregunta

Comment: @VRoxa gracias por el comentario

Comment: Los datos si llegan correctamente, eso lo verifiqué antes de hacer la pregunta, igual con el pipe json me imprime los datos sin problema, el detalle es que necesito en concreto la propiedad "nombre" de "asesorVenta"

Comment: @MiguelAngel Te dejo un ejemplo funcional para hablar sobre lo mismo. Me comentas si te aclara un poco más para entender tu problema mejor.

Comment: Disculpa por responder hasta ahora, estuve revisando el ejemplo funcional y es lo mismo que estoy haciendo, y aun así me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Solamente hasta empresa.asesorVenta se muestra sin problemas, el problema es cuando escribo empresa.asesorVenta.nombre, ahi me arroja el error

Comment: @Legna Al parecer ya me funcionó(no se porqué de primera no me mostraba el nombre), ya me muestra el nombre pero me seguía mostrando el mismo error, y para evitar que me siguiera saliendo el mismo error, agregué una validación al div donde lo muestro de esta forma: `*ngIf="empresa.asesorVenta"`

Comment: Al parecer tus datos no se cargan junto con tu componente

Answer (score 0):

Hola como tu modelo tiene la propiedad de esta forma:

```
public asesorVenta: Array<
```

tendrías que acceder por medio del indice

```html
<p>{{empresa.asesorVenta[0].nombre}}</p>
```